# Nginx how to allow access only /api/ endpoints?

Tags: nginx

My API is located `api.example.com/api` - How I can deny everything else? So a user cannot go, for example, `api.example.com/` or `api.example.com/login`

Unfortunately, this one denied all API traffic as well

```
location ~ /(?!api).* {
    deny all;
}
```

All location settings I have at the moment in my `nginx config file`

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /(?!api).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have an `/index.php` in your config. Is that to be denied also, or is that running your API?

Comment: @RichardSmith index.php boots up my server-side framework, so yeah, it's technically running my API. Hmm, so should I allow index.php & /api/ routes?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your regular expression does not work is that it matches any `/` in the URI that is not followed by `api`. So `/api` and `/api/api` will not be denied, but `/foo` and `/api/foo` will be.

It is easily fixed by adding an anchor (`^`) to the beginning of the regular expression:

```
location ~ ^/(?!api).* { ... }
```

---

An alternative approach uses prefix locations:

```
location / {
    deny all;
}

location /api {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    internal;

    ...
}
```

The `internal` directive prevents direct access to URIs ending with `.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried various combinations but I'm only able to forbid the access to all or nothing. Your suggested alternative approach looked very promising but still, all API calls return 403 as well. Do you have any other suggestions? In the worst-case scenario, I need to handle the redirecting/forbidding at the codebase level. It's not the end of the world but it would be cool to solve this by editing server configs.

Comment: Look at the access log and error log and identify the URI that is causing the 403 response.